# Proven and testable solution architecture when using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture

Not having used EF for a while I decided to refresh my knowledge and do some research. Doing so I came across the familiar articles praising the repository pattern.

However, more interestingly, it seems [more](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) and [more](http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-part-2/) articles popup which debate against the use of the repository pattern in combination with the entity framework.

What I like about the repository pattern is that it makes mocking for your unit tests trivial. What I don't like is that it hides all the queryable linq goodies from the rest of your application.

Since I'm about to setup a new solution architecture I am very interested in learning more about the latter approaches. What does StackOverflow think about them and what other resources are available that back this up?

In short: What is currently the recommended solution architecture utilizing EF6?

Comment: I have been using Repository design with EF and I have not experience any architectural issues. But I am so interested to read all answers provided. Popcorn pls!!!

Comment: Exactly! Yet weirdly enough I have already gotten 2 close votes without comments explaining why. Weird.

Comment: Patterns must be included by some reason, not just because it's supposedly right. Those main reasons often are dependency inversion, decoupling and abstraction. All caused by long distance sight for maintenance and if ifs wipe rotted modules without crashing entire architecture. If you chose your tech, and knew that it is and will be your only choice, then most of patterns can be implemented with slightly or rough cutted corners. Using the one tech you can see its traces around all the project, but deliver really effective solutions. Provided articles make sense but niether is silver bullet!

Comment: Repository is debatable, unit tests (+ mocking) vs. integration tests is debatable. In other words: highly opinion-based.